# Set random number and then randomly decrease it every 5 second until it reaches 0 (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, random

I would like to set a random number between 200  and 300 and then randomly decrease it, step by step every 5 seconds, until it reaches 0.

I only have the beginning where i set the initial number

```
<div id="object_nb"></div>

<script>
function loadRandom() {
     var number_objects = 200 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
      $('#object_nb').text(number_objects);
}
loadRandom(); // initial display
setInterval(function() {
     ???????? // it executes a random decrease every 5sec
  },5000);
</script>
```

How can I achieve this random decrease until 0 ?

Note: i would like to decrease each time the number by a random number ranging from 1 to 5 (not more)

Comment: You already know how to increase by a random number, so it seems unlikely that you don't know how to do the same but decrease instead. What problems did you have when you tried it?

Comment: the loop, like take the previous number and decrease + stop at 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare `number_objects` outside `loadRandom` scope. Have a different function do display the value. Call this function once for initial display and in the interval, decrease the value and display it again.

```
var number_objects; // value in global scope
var displayObject = $('#object_nb'); // fetch object only once, better performace

function loadRandom() {
    number_objects = 200 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
}
function decreaseRandom() {
    // decrease the value by randomly generated value in range 1 - 5
    number_objects -= Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1;        
}
function showRandom() {
    // show / update the value
    displayObject.text(number_objects);
}
loadRandom(); // load the value
showRandom(); // initial display
var interval = setInterval(function () {
    decreaseRandom();
    // display (update) it
    showRandom();
    if(number_objects <= 0) {
        // clear interval when number of objects gets to, or below, 0
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: "`... then randomly decrease it ...`"

Comment: @Teemu how do you define *then randomly decrease it, step by step*? As I understand the definitions, they're mutually exclusive.

Comment: it's great and thanks for the performance. advice but how can I  decrease at every decrease, the number by a random number between 1 and 5; here you decrease each time only by 1

Comment: `function decreaseRandom() { number_objects -= Math.floor(Math.random() * 6); }`

Comment: @JqueryKing that's 0 - 5. You should use `Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1` for interval 1 - 5.

Comment: @MarkoGrešak there's only a little bug: I tried it but once it reaches 1, then it does not decrease to 0 and keep displaying 1 instead of 0. how is that?

Comment: The interval was stopped before the value update, I flipped the statements in my answer. You should also take care of the case where value could be 1 and next random decrease will decrease it by 5, therefore it will display -4. There are different ways to solve this, you better figure best way yourself.